# Lidar in simulation

Tags: ros, simulation, lidar, sensor, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Let's say that I want to add a Lidar sensor (eg. Velodyne 3D) on a robot_description, in simulation. What plugin should I use? My guess is I should use a laser plugin (eg. Libgazebo_ros_laser.so), is that right?

In addition, what is the normal usage of Lidar's data? By this I mean do I use the laserscan directly as input to other nodes like gmapping? Or do I need to first convert laserscan to pointcloud2 or other forms like odom?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50783/lidar-in-simulation/) by [Rookiebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3536/rookiebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest looking at the file urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro in turtlebot_description.  The section beginning

xacro:macro name="turtlebot_sim_laser"

contains a description that creates a lidar sensor on the robot.  Gmapping expects laser scans and odometry as input, so the output of this sensor should work directly.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rookiebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3536/rookiebot/) on 2012-12-20**:
Thanks! I will take a look at the URDF you mentioned.